# Angular one way data bingind not working,

Tags: angularjs

I have to rename customer name to 'Mary' in the 3rd iteration of the number array. As the Angular is 2-way binding all customer name are changed to Mary. Kindly find the attached sample code and help me to fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app ="myApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head><body  data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div >
            <div data-ng-repeat="cust in customer" >
                <div ng-repeat="num in numbers"> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}
                    <div  data-ng-if="num == 4"  data-ng-init="changeCustomer(cust)"></div>
                </div>

             </div>
        </div> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = [{name: 'Jill', city : 'DL'},{name: 'Jack', city : 'KL'}];
    $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $scope.changeCustomer = function(customer) {
            customer.name = 'Mary';
    }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do this kind of logic in controller?What's the result you want?

Comment: Its actually a sub-form inside a form, 
The result i am excepting is :
 Jill - DL
 Jill - DL 
Jill - DL 
Mary - DL
Jill - DL

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
   $scope.customer = [{name: 'Jill', city : 'DL'},{name: 'Jack', city : 'KL'},....];

   $scope.customer[3].name = 'Marry'

   <div ng-repeat="cust in customers"> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}</div>
```

or if it is necessary to call the changeCustomer functions you can use track by $index and avoid nested ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
We have two ng-repeats for customer and number arrays. We are passing the first array obect in the second ng-repeat and trying to change the first array object element in a particular condition. i.e, the name should change to Mary only in the 4th iteration of the second array.
Excepted output : 
Jill - DL
Jill - DL
Jill - DL
Mary - DL
Jill - DL

Comment: could you please help me with a sample
the name should change to Mary only in the 4th iteration of the second array. Excepted output : Jill - DL Jill - DL Jill - DL Mary - DL Jill - DL